# Give a generic version of class BinaryTree that stores instances of a type parameter E

Tags: java, generics, binary-search-tree

Hi in a practice paper for revision I've been given this question.

The class BinaryTree in Question 3 stores integers in a binary tree structure, and method
isInOrder() tests whether the top label of the tree is greater than the top label of the
left subtree and smaller than the top label of the left subtree. A generic form of that class could store instances of any class that implements the Comparable interface:

```
public interface Comparable<T>
{
    public int compareTo(T o);
}
```

Where instance.compareTo(arg) returns a negative value if instance is less
than arg, 0 if instance and arg are equal, and a positive value if instance is greater
than arg. For example, class Integer implements Comparable with
instance.compareTo(arg) returning instance - arg.

(a) Give a generic version of class BinaryTree that stores instances of a type parameter E,
with the requirement that E extends Comparable. Note that you will need to
change the code in the isInOrder() method so that it uses compareTo(). Do
not include a main method in your answer.

The code from the earlier question is here http://pastebin.com/x2p7q3wy

I'm really having trouble wrapping my head around what I have to do for the question and most of the information I have been able to find on generics has just confused me. If anyone could help me with this question or give me a good introduction to generic classes I would be very thankful.

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: The purpose of stackoverflow is not to teach you a language, it is to help you with specific problems. If you do not understand Generics, read a tutorial or your slides/books.

Comment: is this your homework?

Comment: Here is a hint; `class BinaryTree<E extends Comparable<E>>`

Comment: This isn't homework it's a question from a past paper that I'm using to study for an upcoming test.

Comment: It may be too late for your test but it's clear from your question that you don't really understand some of the more basic stuff in Java. I would try studying earlier topics before attempting this question. Specifically, look up things like "What are Generics, why do we use them" and "What is a BinaryTree?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, this is correct:

```
class BinaryTree<E extends Comparable<E>>{

INSERT CODE HERE

}
```

You would then implement all methods of `BinaryTree` - Using `x.compareTo(y)` instead of comparator operators for your `isInOrder()` method. There may be other modifications necessary but I haven't looked at all of your code.

The benefit to this is having a `BinaryTree` class that you can insert any Object into, as long as it implements `Comparable`

Comment: Thank you, I think my main problem was that i couldn't remember the proper structure of a generic class, it seems quite simple now that I know where to start.